# SpringBoot App with Eclipse Link 3. Update version Error - ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

Tags: spring-boot, eclipselink

After update SpringBoot App 2.5.9 and eclipseLink from 2.7.12 to 3.0.0 I got this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2472)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1376)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter.<init>(EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter.java:52)
    at com.config.EclipseLinkJpaConfiguration.createJpaVendorAdapter(EclipseLinkJpaConfiguration.java:38)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:105)
    at com.config.EclipseLinkJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5f9eca68.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$8(<generated>)
    at com.config.EclipseLinkJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5f9eca68$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$54dd22bf.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at com.config.EclipseLinkJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5f9eca68.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 63 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    ... 83 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You changed what from what? Show your dependencies? The fact that you get this is probably you are trying to outsmart the Spring (Boot) dependency management by including individual dependencies with fixed versions, leading to incompatible versions being pulled in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to EclipseLink 3 requires an upgrade to SpringBoot 3x and Java17.

[EclipseLink 3 uses Jakarta Persistence 3](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/)

[SpringBoot 3 is required for Jakarta Persistence 3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0.0-M1-Release-Notes)

[Springboot 3 requires Java 17](https://spring.io/blog/2022/11/24/spring-boot-3-0-goes-ga)

Comment: I moved eclipseLink to 3.0.0, not SpringBoot